# Withdraw ETH from Keythereum wallets

Tags: node.js, ethereum, private-key

So I was using [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) to generate public and private keys.

```
const dk = ethereum.create();
parameters.address = ethereum.privateKeyToAddress(dk.privateKey);
parameters.pKey = dk.privateKey.toString('hex');
```

Now I have send some ETH to the generated wallet and it worked. The challenge I am facing is with withdrawal.

Anyone knows how I can withdraw the ETH from the generated wallet, I tried searching with no luck.

I know for BTC we can use [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info) to import the private keys. Is there a similar service for ETH too.

Thank you so much

Comment: You can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ with the exported private key.

Comment: Besides MyEtherWallet, you can in practice import the raw private hex key to any Ethereum wallet.